# Error message: "The following files did not self-register or unregister"

Tags: windows-10

I have a program that I am trying to install on a local PC running Windows 10 Enterprise, but the following error comes up at the end of the installation process:

"The following files did not self-register or unregister: oleaut32.dll access is denied"

I've tried starting Windows and installing the program in Safe Mode under an Admin profile, manually registering oleaut32.dll, and running sfc /scannow. The program still triggers this error and won't run correctly. Any ideas as to how to fix the error?

The program is Crescendo Admin, found here:
https://www.crescendointeractive.com/software/crescendo-admin.html

This isn't a VB6 application that I'm aware of.

Comment: Are you attempting to do OLE Automation by chance?  Is this a VB6 application by chance?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I'm not - the software is for financial reporting.

Comment: You have verified that `oleaut32.dll` is in the **syswow64** directory?  The file is 32-bit based on the filename and the fact it appears to be linked to VB6 software (which is always 32-bit).

Comment: It is in syswow64 and in System32

Comment: `oleaut32.dll` is directly linked to VB6 software.  It shouldn't be in both directories, it should only exist in `syswow64`, since it's a 32-bit file.  It's entirely possible the software you attempting to use, has not been updated, to properly run on 64-bit version of Windows.  I would attempt to run it within a 32-bit Windows VM to confirm that fact.  Update your question instead of submitting any additional comments.

Comment: The DLL might be in use. Try it when booting in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've trawled the internet for an answer to this issue.
I have an issue at work with a client machine, that fails to install Canon 4010 Scanner drivers, because of an error:

ERROR MESSAGE:
The following files did not self-register or unregister:
**C:\WINDOWS\system32\Oleaut32.dll Access is denied**

so many posts advise to register the DLL, which failed on my initial attempts. I also see many people writing posts on multiple forums stating they were having issues registering this DLL, despite being able to register other DLLs without a problem.
In my case, the DLLs failed to register simply because of a syntax error in my CMD command.
Anyone else who runs into this issue, please try all 4 x CMD commands below - one or more should work:

COMMAND 1
**C:\Windows\SysWow64\regsvr32.exe C:\windows\system32\oleaut32.dll**

COMMAND 2
**C:\Windows\SysWow64\regsvr32.exe C:\windows\syswow64\oleaut32.dll**

COMMAND 3
**C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe C:\windows\system32\oleaut32.dll**

COMMAND 4
**C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe C:\windows\syswow64\oleaut32.dll**

the differences between the 2 x versions of RegSVR32 are, as Microsoft put it:

The 64-bit version is **%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe.**
The 32-bit version is **%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe.**

**resource:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages-a98d960a-7392-e6fe-d90a-3f4e0cb543e5**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found is to right-click on the install file and select the "**Troubleshoot Compatibility**" option. From here select "**Try Recommended Settings**" next select "**Test The Program**" the file should then install error-free.

Afterwords click "**Next**" and then "**Yes, save these settings for the program**"